# Sonata batch action ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery is empty

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using createQuery() function in Admin class to override list query but when i'm using batchAction to perform the batch action

```
public function batchActionArchive(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery){
  $selectedModels = $selectedModelQuery->execute();

  // $selectedModels is always empty 
}
```

when i override proxyQuery it returned empty but when i dont it returned selected results.

Please help how can i resolve this issue